# How to learn to use make? I'm never ever able to build sources with make and makefiles

Tags: makefile

I'm new to *N*X OSes, actually MacOS, and when I try to build sources with make and makefiles, I never can.
I try to run make, even try to run it passing the makefile as an argument, but all I get is "There's nothing for make to do"
Can you point me to a tutorial, reference, or something ?

Comment: what is the exact command line your are using?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not using any as I don't have any idea of how to do it. For some sources, I just get into the source directory, run make and everything works, but with others, make returns with the message "there's nothing for make to do" and without any further instructions, I don't have any idea of how to build that soft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you're trying to install from a tarball there will be a file named README or INSTALL with installation instructions. Usually all you have to do is run from the terminal

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

It's generally possible to set options for compilation by adding flags to `./configure`, to see what they are run

```
./configure --help
```

Answer (score 2):

This [one](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile) is excellent.

(You can also read some [criticism](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile) to round your knowledge.)

(If after reading these, you want to try cmake, then you want to go [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html). It works perfectly on Mac OS X.)

Comment: The first two links are dead now.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm) is a tutorial to help you get started.

Just remember to use tabs instead of spaces when indenting lines in the makefile :)

Comment: I don't make makefiles, I just want to be able to download some sources and build them into an executable.

Comment: OK. Do you have an example of a piece of software that you are having trouble with? Normally there are instructions in a README.txt or something. And often you have to run ./configure *before* you run make.